# How to control Stream (start, pause, resume) in Streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to three-row share one stream and each row can pause and resume.

Now, I just can using `StreamController` and `StreamBuilder` share one stream to three-row, but I don't know how to pause and resume.

[image]

https://github.com/WingCH/Fluuter-Exercise

```dart
...
class StreamDemoState extends State<StreamDemo> {
  StreamController _streamController;
  Stream<int> timerStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //Timer
    Duration interval = Duration(seconds: 1);
    timerStream = Stream.periodic(interval, (data) {
      return data;
    });

    _streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
    _streamController.addStream(timerStream);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
    Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 80),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            OutlineButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                //listen / resume
                              },
                              child: Text('listen'),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                              child: OutlineButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  //Pause
                                },
                                child: Text('Paused'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            OutlineButton(
                              onPressed: null,
                              child: Text('--'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text('no Date');
                  }
                }),
          ),
...
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing the same problem and this is what I came up with:
Instead of calling addStream on your StreamController, you can add the events one by one with a listener on timerStream. listen returns a StreamSubscription that you can pause the intStream with SubscriberSubsription.pause.

Replace `_streamController.addStream(timerStream);` with the following (I haven't run this myself so there may be some typos):

```
var _timerSubscription = timerStream.listen((event) => _streamController.add(event));
```

now you can replace `//resume` and `//pause` with the following, respectively:

```
// Resume
_timerSubscription.resume();
```

```
// Pause
_timerSubscription.pause();
```

Note that a stream paused with multiple calls to `pause()` will require an equal number of calls to `resume()` to unpause-if this is undesired behavior you'll want to disable the pause button (or simply skip the call to pause() in onPressed if the stream is already paused).

Also, don't forget to cancel your StreamSubscription and close your StreamController when they're no longer in use!